# Wordpress jQuery Menu Modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to alter a Wordpress menu dropdown e.g. when solutions is hovered over I want to create and append a new div with class '.solutions-dd' to the menu and inside it I want to place the existing Wordpress dropdown. I've got this working as intended: 
http://bit.ly/1KhVNAq

However it fails to work on some pages: http://bit.ly/1Fx2LQY

I can't see any Javascript errors, nor can see any difference in the menu to cause it to fail on some pages.

jQuery used:

```
<!-- Custom Solutions Menu Dropdown -->
$("li.solutions").mouseover(function(){ /*On mouse over*/
    $("<div class='solutions-dd'></div>").appendTo("#sector-choice"); /*Append new div to div #sector-choice*/
    $("li.solutions ul.sub-menu").appendTo(".solutions-dd");/*Append existing dropdown to new #sector-choice div*/
});

/*Remove new div & styles on mouse when mousing over over divs*/
$('.home, .about, .products, .customer, .Recommendations, .contact, #masthead, .entry-content, #article').mouseover(function(){
    $(".solutions-dd ul.sub-menu").appendTo("li.solutions");
    $( ".solutions-dd" ).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it fails in some pages because it conflicts with other jQuery plugins. You can try replacing `$` with `jQuery`

Learn more about [jQuery noConflict wrappers](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers)

Comment: Can I ask how you determined that? I'm not reading any errors.